# Moltin iOS V2 - Loading Images is a pain

Tags: ios, json, api, moltin

I have been trying to work with the Moltin Ecommerce API V2. I have looked at the example document, worked through it and nothing works.  I came to the point where I started copying the whole document as is... Wait for it... NOTHING WORKS.

I took a small example to just load an image using api. Followed the instructions the T but nothing.

Is there anyone here that knows what the problem is? 
Secondly - must you use Alamofire for web requests?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve your chances of getting help, read through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, your question as phrased currently is too broad and is not reproducible.

Comment: I have found the following link; https://forum.moltin.com/t/rendering-the-main-image-from-the-id/114/8 It seems like you need to request the image object when you are requesting your products.  Unfortunately, the Moltin quick-start is out-dated and lacks important information.  I would avoid following it.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a ticket for this with Moltin.

They have now updated the API call to the following:

```
private func loadProducts() {
let query = MoltinQuery(offset: nil, limit: 20, sort: nil, filter: nil, include: [.main_image])
Moltin.product.list(withQuery: query) { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Failed to get products:\n\(error)")
    case .success(let productList):
        print(productList)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.productsCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

}